# Using ConfigurationBuilder to read setting and use AddAzureKeyVault

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp-net-config-builders

I have the following but in order to use `AddAzureKeyVault` I need to know the key vault name which is set in configuration. Is it possible to read in this value in one go or do I need to build it twice?

```
    private static IConfigurationRoot GetIConfigurationRoot()
    {
        var root = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            //.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
                
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you add your configuration like that, but it is possible in with `ConfigurationManager` for example :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connStringAzureKV= builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureKV");
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(connStringAzureKV);
```

Or

```
var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager();
configurationManager.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
configurationManager.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var connStringAzureKV = configurationManager.GetConnectionString("AzureKV");
configurationManager.AddAzureKeyVault(connStringAzureKV);
```

`ConfigurationManager` implements both `IConfigurationManager` and `IConfigurationRoot`, so it should work in your case.

Not sure what kind of host are you building, but using the first example is always good option.

When you build your `IConfigurationRoot` I don't see a way to add more configuration sources.

NOTE This is also valid:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot GetIConfigurationRoot()
 {
     var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager();
     configurationManager.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
     configurationManager.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
     var connStringAzureKV = configurationManager.GetConnectionString("AzureKV");
     configurationManager.AddAzureKeyVault(connStringAzureKV);

     return configurationManager;
 }
```

I used `GetConnectionString` just for sake of example, you can get your configuration from every section in `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add azure key vault configuration after build.

```
private static IConfigurationRoot GetIConfigurationRoot()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    var root = builder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{root["AzureKeyVault:Name"]}.vault.azure.net");
    return root;
}
```